# How to connect to "host:port" but no using browser, just node js/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

to conenct to server (created with node js), we samplely open browser and some file with code similar to:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
// Send messages to server:
    function envioas(){
        socket.emit('operepues', 'envio');
        }
// Listen messages from server:
    socket.on('rdsdo', function(data){
        document.getElementById('msj').innerHTML = data
        });
/*]]>*/</script>
<div id="msj"></div>
```

But please,
just I need create this connection from file.js in server!
I need listen message from server and send message to server in port 8080 from OTHER server.js listenning in port 666 or any OTHER...

I try with:

```
...code JS...
io = require('socket.io');
socket2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
var socket2 = io.connect(socket2);
socket.emit('send_to_emit', typeof(socket2));
...code JS...
```

and EVER 'send_to_emit' is "undefinied".

I need connect FROM file_server01.js (file JS/node_JS in server 01)
to file_server02.js (file JS/node_JS in server 02)
without used browser, only code JS "pure".

Sorry by repeat target multiple times, but my english is poor...

Regards!

Comment: **socket.io** works perfectly with nodejs, too ... see the related npm package for more.

Comment: Try to use `const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:8080')` and then `socket.emit` and `socket.on`

Comment: Thanks mk12ok.Just with your indication: "require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:8080')" I get my target: """ socket33 = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
 socket33.emit('sendMSJ', MSJ);
 socket33.on('listenMSJ', function(data){
  instructions...;
  });
"""

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) or https.request